Google chrome tab crashing when using VSCode
Google chrome tab crashing when using VSCode.
I am working on my Django Rest framework and React project. Whenever I am trying to work on it google chrome tab is crashing. I am using Windows.
Has anyone else resolved this issue earlier?
I have reinstalled VSCode.
I have also disabled all the extensions.
I don't know how to resolve this issue.

Can you show us the Chrome logs?  You'll need to enable logging first.
